# Why is "reputation_change" missing on some dates for some users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stack-exchange, reputation-history, api

I am trying to understand the reputation log returned by Stack Exchange API `/users/{ids}/reputation`. Most reputation logs have `reputation_change`, which is the value of reputation change on that date, for instance:

```
  "items": [
    {
      "on_date": 1583168476,
      "reputation_change": 10,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 748328,
      "user_id": 71909
    }
```

But occasionally, I run into logs with no `reputation_change`, for instance:

```
  "items": [
    {
      "on_date": 1583127369,
      "vote_type": "up_votes",
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 72899,
      "user_id": 12398
    }
```

Why is it the case? Did this particular / Can any `up_votes` not change the user's reputation?

Comment: It’s probably due to the [reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160/289905).

Comment: @user4642212 - But in this case, user:12398's reputation in total is only 118, less than the 200 daily limit...

Comment: Ah, this upvote is on [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72899/4642212), which is a community wiki. However, I can’t tell why another 1930 votes aren’t mentioned there. Their [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12398/masi?tab=reputation) only shows three upvotes on this post (with no reputation changes). The post’s timeline doesn’t reveal anything special about those three votes either.

Comment: I see. Thank you @user4642212